# Texture bug - problem

Tags: texturing, uv, uv-image-editor

The question was solved but caused also a new problem as you can see here: [image]
How can I get a correct wall without the sligts (more work with the uv maps) in it?

SOLVED (OLD) PROBLEM:
some of my objects don't to like to get textured, as you can see in this picture: (Hi btw ;)

[image]

[image]

In the last picture I tried to sperate the buggy part of the object with its own UV map, but without a better result:
[image]

I use UV maps (1. object mode ctrl+a -> scale ; 2. edit mode a; 3. edit mode n; 4. edit mode mark seam; 5. edit mode unwrap)

Do you have any idea what the problem might be?

Greetings and thanks a lot!

Marc

B)
[image]

Comment: It looks like potentially some double vertices, why don't you try removing doubles. Also, uploading a blend file makes answering a question like this much easier: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer! :) Good idea, but it didn't help. I uploaded the wall here: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=4811" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/4811/)

Comment: There's no bug, you mesh has bad topology. Avoid NGons use quad based meshes to avoid these and many other kinds of problems

Comment: Thanks a lot Duarte Farrajota Ramos! It fixed the problem (I used the instructions of this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=axCYMBRMXo0 ) but also caused another as you can see in the last picture (B). Do you have any idea how to fix the problem and get at best just the one texture on a side of the wal, without any slides in it?

Comment: Please don't edit your questions with answer and include new question in the body of the first one, that's not how it's supposed to work here (readability decreases anyway). If you found solution to your first problem post it in the Answer section below and accept the answer; then ask new question with your new problem